# Why does the specification of the batch_size parameter in a keras input object not replace the ?/None entry?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras, batch-normalization

I I want to compute a value (similarity/distance) between all my encoded vectors during the loss function but this is not possible because I can not access the batch dimension. For this reason, I want to define them as a fixed value via keras input object with the parameter batch_size. But this does not work.

how do I get a fixed value instead ?/None entry for the batch dimension in a tensorflow keras model?

```
input= tf.keras.Input(shape=(20, 20, 3), batch_size=64, name="Input0")
```

**Input dim:  (?, 20, 20, 3)**

How do I set this ? value fixed during model compile so it is a fixed value in the graph?

Comment: I think you are drowning in a glass of water, what makes you think computing a metric over a batch is somehow not possible due to the batch dimension? How do losses such as mean squared error do it then?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy My output is (?,50) where ? is equal 64. Now I want to compute the Euclidean distance betweem all 64 vectors and compute the mean. I will compute 64*64 distances. A large value should increase the loss. A small value is favoured. How do I compute this value? The compilation of the model fails because of this unspecific dimension in the loss function.